# Incluir caracteres especiales en un parámetro con Blazor

Tags: blazor

estoy intentando pasar un parámetro para realizar una búsqueda en Blazor. Este parámetro es una cadena que puede contener caracteres especiales como +, /, o #. Ya que si se intenta una búsqueda como "libro C++" o "libro C#" la URL o cadena de consulta es valida y debe regresar el resultado. Mas sin embargo regresa error 404 y esto sucede por los caracteres especiales. ya que si ingreso "C" no hay problema pero si ingreso "C#" si... ¿es posible pasar este tipo de cadenas como parámetro en blazor?,
¿Cómo puedo lograrlo?

Answer (score 0):

Tienes problema con enrutado. Al escribir caracteres especiales no se va a tu pagina, sino busca otra pagina, no la encuentra y por esto te da error 404.

Puedes solucionar lo de diferentes maneras:

1. En lugar de utilizar parametros con el metodo GET y meter los en URL, utiliza URL para mostrar los resultados pero la cadena de busqueda la tienes que pasar por el metodo POST y luego recoger este parametro no desde URL, sino desde la petición.
2. Antes de enviar la cadena convierte los caracteres especiales en codigos que son aceptables y una vez lo recibes en otro lado - inviertes la conversion.
3. Utiliza aceptación de cualquier cadena (uso de catch-all), ej.: `@page "/catalog/{*data}"`. El problema en este caso que no podras tener rutas similares, tendran que ser bastante diferentes. Por ejemplo:

- Pagina 1 (funciona): `@page "/busqueda/resultado/{*cadenabuscada}"`
- Pagina 2 (no funcionara, se ira a Pagina 1): `@page "/busqueda/resultado/{cadenabuscada}/{formato}"`
- Pagina 3 (funciona): `@page "/busqueda/resultados/{xxxx}"`